# keep tableViewCell at the same position after setEditing is being enabled in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm facing a problem of editng tableViewCell.Whenever the tableview is enabled for editing the cells move to right. Though I kept `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)rearrangeButton:(id)sender {

    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

The default tableViewCell:

[image]

After tableviewCell editing is being enabled:

[image]

How to keep the cell at its default position after editing is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing dear developers. I got the answer. Its

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```